# categorical scatter plot using d3.js javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I need to make a scatter plot for some categorical data for rainfall in 3 cities for 3 years using d3.js:

```
Year1    Year2    Year3
NY CA TX NY CA TX NY CA TX
17 20 15 23 10 11 14 15 17
16 18 12 15 21 22 20 18 19
13 22 16 17 25 18 17 25 18
19 18 13 16 21 20 22 15 16
```

[image: This is how the graph should look like]
(Note: the data and plot do not match here, it is just to explain my query)
I am completely new to d3.js. I have attempted some tutorials for simple scatterplots and bar graphs, but I can't figure out how do I display a categorical graph like this one.

Any help to get me started would be appreciated.

[edit]
I rearranged the data in the tsv file so it looks like this:

```
year    state    rain
1   NY  17
1   NY  16
1   NY  13
1   CA  20
1   TX  15
2   NY  23
3   CA  10
3   TX  14
3   NY  13
```

There seems to be some problem. I get "Unexpected value NaN parsing cx attribute." and same for cy. Any idea how can I fix it?

```
var newArray = new Array();
        // draw the scatterplot
        svg.selectAll("dot")                                    // provides a suitable grouping for the svg elements that will be added
            .data(data)                                         // associates the range of data to the group of elements
        .enter().append("circle")                               // adds a circle for each data point
            .attr("r", 5)                                     // with a radius of 3.5 pixels
            .attr("cx", function (d) {

                 newArray = data.filter( function (el) {
                    return el.category == "NY";
                });

                return xScale(newArray.rain);
            })      // at an appropriate x coordinate 
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return yScale(newArray.year);
            })  // and an appropriate y coordinate
            .style("fill", color(9));
```

Comment: The [NVD3 scatterplot](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : I have to use d3 only. I updated the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: NVD3 is based on D3. I can't really help you unless you show us the complete code.

Comment: @user1340852 have you found some method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this in d3, with their own pluses and minuses.

Frankly, this question is too vague for this forum, but I found the challenge you present kind of interesting. So I mocked up one way to do the Y axis. http://jsfiddle.net/7Jpw2/2/

It uses an ordinal scale for the states and another ordinal scale for the years overlaid on top of the first one

This may not be a complete answer, but it should get you going pretty far.

```
var categories = [
    { year:3, state:'NY' },
    { year:3, state:'CA' },
    { year:3, state:'TX' },
    { year:2, state:'NY' },
    { year:2, state:'CA' },
    { year:2, state:'TX' },
    { year:1, state:'NY' },
    { year:1, state:'CA' },
    { year:1, state:'TX' }
];

// IMPORTANT! This is a way to make each state @ year unique, by returning a concatenation of state and year
categories.forEach(function(cat) {
    cat.toString = function() { return this.state + '_' + this.year }
});

// These year values should ideally be extracted from categories array above, not hardcoded as below
var years = ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3'];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

// Create 2 axes:
// First a state-name axis
// Then a year axis, in which everything except the text is invisible (via css fill:none)

var statesScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(categories)
    .rangeBands([50,300]);
var statesAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient('left')
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d.state; })
    .scale(statesScale)

var yearsScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(years)
    .rangeBands([50,300]);
var yearsAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient('left')
    .tickSize(50) // Distances the year label from state labels
    .scale(yearsScale)


svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'states-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(150,0)')
    .call(statesAxis);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'years-axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(150,0)')
    .call(yearsAxis);
```